# Way to run python in VSCODE.dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, chromebook

is there a way I can run python code in vscode .dev, im looking for a way to do this on a school Chromebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the Python extension in VSCODE.dev, and then run the file with a [Jupyter Server](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Connecting-to-a-remote-Jupyter-server-from-vscode.dev) by right clicking and choosing "Run Current File in Interactive Window." **HOWEVER: You must run the Jupyter Server on some computer (if you're chromebook has the Linux Development Environment enabled, you could do it there). You could run it on a remote computer, but that will cost money.**